# Neyman - Pearson - Test with Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let $X$ be a Poi($\nu$) distributed rv with unknown $\nu \in (0,\infty)$ and we set $ \theta:=\nu $. We want to test the hypotheses $ H_0:\nu_0=1 $ against $ H_1:\nu_1=\nu_0=2 $

a) We look at the (randomized) Neyman - Pearson - Test which has the form

$T(k) = \begin{cases}
1 & R(k) > c \\
\gamma & R(k)=c \\
0 & R(k)<c
\end{cases}$
, with $c \in \mathbb{R} $ and $\gamma \in [0,1]$

$ R(k) := \frac{P_{\nu_1}(X=k)}{P_{\nu_0}(X=k)} $ is the Maximum Liklihood quotient.

Compute $c^*$ and $ \gamma^* $ such that $T$ is a test with niveau $\alpha = 0.05$ i.e. $E_{\nu_0}[T]=\alpha$.

b) You see that $X=3$. How do you decide in terms of the test wich you construct in a)?

Values of a Poi($\nu$) distributed rv for task a')

$ P(X\leq 0) = 0.368$

$P(X\leq 1) = 0.736$

$P(X\leq 2) = 0.92$

$P(X\leq 3) = 0.981$

$P(X\leq 4) = 0.996$

$P(X\leq 5) = 0.999$

I have computed $ R(k) = \frac{e^{-2n} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2^{k_i}}{k_i !} }{e^{-n}\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{k_i !}} = e^2 2^{\sum_{i=1}^n k_i} $.

But how can i now compute $c^*$? If i have $c^*$ then i can compute $\gamma^*$ with the fact that

$ E_{\nu_0}[T] = P(R(k)>c^*) + \gamma^* P(R(k)=c^*) = 0.05 = \alpha  $

Comment: You can easily find $c^\ast$ based on your info on $P_{\nu_0}(X\leq t)$. Find the values for $P_{\nu_0}(X>t)$ and then $c^\ast$ will be the smallest $t$ such that the probability is at most $\alpha$.

Comment: so, do i calculate $ 1-P(X \leq k $ for the given values and the nearest value to 0.05 is my $c^*$ ?

Comment: Yes, you calculate these values, but then it's not necessarily the closest one to 0.05, but the first one below it. As a toy example, if in some other case you have $P_{\nu_0}(X>57)=0.06$ and $P_{\nu_0}(X>58)=0.01$, then $c^\ast=58$.

Comment: thank you Mau314. So in my case $c^*$ would be 3, or not?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Now what do you get for $\gamma*$?

Comment: for $\gamma^*$ i get the explict formula $ \gamma^* = \frac{0.05 - P(R(k)>3)}{P(R(k)=3)} $. But i am not sure how to calculate $ P(R(k))>3 $.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. It seems you have $n=1$, so $R(X)=e^{-1}2^X$. Since this function is strictly increasing, we have $P(X>c^\ast)=P(R(X)>e^{-1}2^{c^\ast})$ and can set $c=e^{-1}2^{c^\ast}$. So either you go with $X>3$ or you go with $R(X)>8/e$, they are equivalent with probability $0.019$.

Comment: Because of $ P(R(k)>3) = 0.019 $ and $ P(R(k)=3) = 0.981 $ i get for $ \gamma^*=0.0316 $

Comment: Not really. Note that $P(R(X)=8/e)=P(X=3)=P(X\leq 3)-P(X\leq 2)=0.61$ and that leads to $\gamma\approx 0.51$.

Comment: thank you very much Mau314! i got it. To b): is it enaugh to say, if we see that $X=3$ the hypotheses $H_0$ is accepted?

Comment: Yes. Or rather, it's not rejected :)

Comment: thanks again :D